Svelte 5 bind value is getting more complex
I migrate my progect to svelte 5 and start using the power of runes but the code is buggy because the bind is not working anymore and i had to add some extra line of code. Here and example before and after the migration. I personally think in svelte 4 was way much simpler. Do you think i can make it better?
Before:
export let data: PageData;

<Player bind:data={data.news} />
<Actions bind:data={data.news} />

After:
interface Props { 
  data: PageData;
}
let { data }: Props = $props();
let news: Data = $state(data.news);
page.subscribe(() => (news = data.news));

<Player bind:data={data.news} />
<Actions bind:data={data.news} />


You actually don't need to add types to props in the SvelteKit specific Svelte files (SvelteKit figure them out on its own), so you don't need to use the Props interface you have.

Thanks @PeppeL-G is always appreciate less code :) but why now the data from the server is not reacting anymore and i need to subscribe to the store, also the {#key data} is not working.

In Svelte 5, using bind as you do in <Player bind:data={WHATEVER} /> only makes sense when WHATEVER is a reactive variable (i.e. created with $state()). Otherwise reactive re-computations won't trigger when the prop is assigned a new value in the child. The data prop you receive in your +page.svelte components is not a reactive variable created with $state(), so even though you bind to it when you pass it as a prop to a child component, changes the child makes to that prop won't trigger any re-computations/re-renderings in the parent component.

You can't use bind:data={data.news}, because the data prop you receive from SvelteKit isn't reactive.

If the prop is a regular object, the mutation will have no effect [...]
https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte/$props

But bind:data={news} should make the reactivity work, since your own news variable is created as a reactive variable.

Do you think i can make it better?

Your own data prop is a too general name which will make your code too hard to read. If the data represents a news article, then I would have named it newsArticle.

Ok but the problem is that now is not react anymore if the pageload new data, i need to set manually the change in the page subscribtion and in svelte 4 was working just fine.

There was rune for linking state before but that was removed.
The intended way to synchronize state that also needs to be written to, is to use an effect.
It should be this:
let news = $state(data.news);
$effect.pre(() => { news = data.news; });

You generally should not manually subscribe to stores, the subscription is not cleaned up automatically; you have to clean it up manually.
If  you want to use a store with runes in a component, use the $-syntax in an $effect or $derived. So if you want to use the page store, e.g.:
const id = $derived($page.params.id);


Is it wrong to use let news = $derived($state(data.news))? I admit that it's a bit contradictory that a derived value is updateable, but on the other hand I find this a bit cleaner than your two lines of code. Assuming that this actually works, which I haven't tested ^^'

@PeppeL-G: It does not work. $state cannot be nested like that and assignments to a $derived variable will also cause a Svelte compiler error.

Thanks @brunnerh this $effect.pre do the job instead of page.subscribe but why now i need to do this, before was working just fine, i have another page where i have more than 20 values and now i need to combine each one of that?

@MarcelloKabora: I don't think you need to extract each property, it should be possible to make the entire data reactive via a state.
